# Returning value from eventListener callback

Tags: javascript, async-await, addeventlistener, anonymous-function

My program contains 2 functions, one to fetch a random joke from https://api.chucknorris.io/ and the other to display the joke on a webpage.

I think the problem lies in returning "joke.value" from the anon function in the event listener. I can return a value without using the event listener but I want to know how to achieve it using it if possible.

```
    <script> 
    // function fetches joke onclick 
    const generateJoke = () => {
        
        let button = document.querySelector("button");
        
        button.addEventListener("click", async () => {
            try{
                const response = await fetch("https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random");
                const joke = await response.json();
                return joke.value;
            }
            catch (error){
                console.error(error);
            }
        })
    // call print function to display joke content to the page
        
       printJoke(joke.value);
    }

    const printJoke = async (joke) => {

        let jokeList = document.getElementById("jokeDisplay");
        let jokeItem = document.createElement("p");

        jokeItem.innerHTML = joke;
        
        jokeList.appendChild(jokeItem);
    }

    
    </script>
```

When my code runs nothing happens when I click the button.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need the generateJoke function. Also if you put printJoke(joke.value) inside the try your code will work.

```
let button = document.querySelector(".button-item");
        button.style.color ='red';
        button.addEventListener("click", async () => {
            try{
                const response = await fetch("https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random");
                const joke = await response.json();
                console.log(joke);
                printJoke(joke.value);
            }
            catch (error){
                console.error(error);
            }
        })
```